# Alignment (16-byte) of intermediate pointers dynamically

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, memory-alignment

Suppose we have this code:

```
float *data = (float*)_mm_malloc(N*sizeof(float), 16);//allocate 16-byte aligned array of N elements
const int loop_bound1 = .....;//some value
const int loop_step  = .....;//some value
const int loop_bound2 = ....;//some value
for(auto i=0; i<loop_bound; i+=loop_step)
{
    auto inter_data1 = data + i;//inter_data1 may be not aligned
    for(int j=0; j<loop_bound2; ++j)
    {
        auto inter_data2 = inter_data1 + j;//inter_data2 also may be not aligned
        __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(inter_data2);//it's ok, but I want use _mm_load_ps instead
    }
}
```

Invoking **_mm_load_ps** instead of **_mm_loadu_ps** requires to keep **inter_data1** and **inter_data2** 16-byte aligned.
What is the best (safe and with minimum overhead) way for aligning these poinetrs? I consider **std::align**, but I'm not sure that is correct choice.

Comment: You're stepping through your array in 4-byte chunks (sizeof float), so you'll certainly be 16-byte aligned only on every 4th access. But you seem to be _loading_ 16-byte chunks. If you really need your chunks to overlap like this, they _can't_ all be aligned. If they shouldn't overlap, your loop is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the memory with `_aligned_malloc` on Windows or `memalign` on Linux, then your pointers will be aligned on the stack. Or, if you want to align the memory on the heap then you can use `#pragma pack`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard implementations would use:

```
__declspec( align( n ) )
```

... where 'n' is the number of bytes you need to align your datatype to.  You can build some macros for various alignments, such as:

```
#define AALIGN( n )    __declspec( align( n ) )
#define AALIGN4        __declspec( align( 4 ) )
#define AALIGN8        __declspec( align( 8 ) )
#define AALIGN16       __declspec( align( 16 ) )
#define AALIGN32       __declspec( align( 32 ) )
#define AALIGN64       __declspec( align( 64 ) )
```

... and then you can declare your data like:

```
AALIGN16 float m_fMyAlignedFloat;
```

Hope that helps!